# How to detect if React child element is overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

tldr; How do I make my component hide the overflow and make it "toggle" views with a button. ex) user can initially see tab 1,2,3 and 4,5,6 is hidden, a button click will hide the 1,2,3 and show 4,5,6 now (without knowing that the screen will cut after 1,2,3)

I'm trying to make a navbar that can be reused in any screen size. My goal is to allow developers to dynamically add tabs (which is a child element) to the navbar without it overflowing. In the case where the navbar overflows, meaning it makes a new row because it reached its max width, a clickable arrow key goes to the next set of tabs. This is my code so far. How can I achieve this behavior?

Navbar.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Tab from './Tab';
import { StyledTabs } from '../styledComponents/StyledNavbar';
import { NavbarOutline } from '../styledComponents/StyledNavbar';

const Navbar = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(children[0].props.label);

  const onClickTabItem = tab => {
    setActiveTab(tab);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <NavbarOutline>
        <ol>
          {children.map(child => {
            const { label } = child.props;
            return <Tab activeTab={activeTab} key={label} label={label} handleClick={onClickTabItem} />;
          })}
        </ol>
      </NavbarOutline>
      <div>
        {children.map(child => {
          if (child.props.label !== activeTab) return undefined;
          return <StyledTabs className="content">{child.props.children}</StyledTabs>
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Tab.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyledTabs } from '../styledComponents/StyledNavbar';

const Tab = props => {
  const { activeTab, label, handleClick } = props;
  let className = 'not-active';

  const onClick = () => {
    handleClick(label);
  };

  if (activeTab === label) {
    className = 'active';
  }

  return (
    <StyledTabs className={className} onClick={onClick}>
      {label}
    </StyledTabs>
  );
};
export default Tab;
```

EDIT: here is my css as well; I used styled components for styling

StyledNavbar.js

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const NavbarOutline = styled.div`
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e3e3e3;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 35px;
`;

export const StyledTabs = styled.button.attrs(props => ({
  className: props.className,
}))`
  &.not-active {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 16px 31px 16px 31px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
  }
  &.active {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    padding: 16px 31px 16px 31px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #2b8000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2b8000;
  }
  &.content {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 35px;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a CSS issue, it would be great if you could've attached the css as well. However, you can solve this using flexbox. Add the following css to the parent container to ensure the tabs create a new row instead of overflowing,

```css
.flex-item {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap li {
  background: gold;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ol class="flex-container wrap">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
  <li class="flex-item">9</li>
  <li class="flex-item">10</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but this wasn't what I was trying to do. I want to make sure my component doesn't make a new row but instead hide the overflow and make it "toggle" views with a button. ex) if a user can initially see tab 1,2,3 and 4,5,6 is hidden, a button click will hide the 1,2,3 and show 4,5,6 now. I hope that makes sense.